# JPARepository deleteAllInBatch() not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to delete some rows from my table using Spring JPA deleteAllInBatch() but when the number of rows to be deleted exceed some threshold value JPA throws error. I'm not certain the cause of this error but found a jira ticket : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-137.

I don't want to use deleteAll() as it deletes the data one by one and will lead to performance issues. Is this a drawback of JPA or there's some solution to it. I tried for some workaround but didn't found anything much useful. Please help me to get an efficient solution for this operation or some useful references. Thanks in advance...

DbIssueApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DbIssueApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DbIssueApplication.class, args);
        TestService service = context.getBean(TestService.class);

        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>();        
        for(int i=0;i<5000;i++)
        {
            testList.add(new Test(i,(i%2==0)?"field1":"field2"));
        }
        service.insert(testList);


        service.deleteByName("field2");

        System.err.println("The processing took = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-st)+" ms");
    }

}
```

Test.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9182756617906316269L;
    @Id
    private Integer id; 
    private String name;

        ... getter,setter and constructors

}
```

TestRepository.java

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> 
{
    List<Test> findByName(String name);
}
```

TestService.java

```
public interface TestService 
{
    public void insert(List<Test> testList);
    public void deleteByName(String name);
}
```

TestServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService 
{
    @Autowired
    TestRepository testRepository;

    @Override
    public void insert(List<Test> testList) 
    {
        testRepository.deleteAllInBatch();
        testRepository.saveAll(testList);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByName(String name)
    {
        System.err.println("The number of rows to be deleted = "+testRepository.findByName(name).size());
        testRepository.deleteInBatch(testRepository.findByName(name));
    }


}
```

dbSchema

```
create table test
(
    id int,
    name varchar(40)
);
```

ErrorLog

```
[           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl                : begin
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : parse() - HQL: delete from com.example.demo.entity.Test x where x = ?1 or x = ?2 or x = ?3 or x = ?4 or ...  x = ?2500
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
[           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl                : rolling back
[      Thread-14] o.h.i.SessionFactoryImpl                 : HHH000031: Closing
[      Thread-14] o.h.t.s.TypeConfiguration$Scope          : Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@6cf001] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@1ad3d8a]
[      Thread-14] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
[      Thread-14] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries

=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================

[           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : QueryTranslatorFactory : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@5e167a
[           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.example.demo.entity.Test as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.name=:param0
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'example'
    |  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'demo'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'entity'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Test'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
       \-[EQ] Node: '='
          +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
          |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'name'
          \-[COLON] Node: ':'
             \-[IDENT] Node: 'param0'

[           main] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromElement                  : FromClause{level=1} : com.example.demo.entity.Test (generatedAlias0) -> test0_
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> test0_.id
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> test0_.id
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.t.DotNode                      : getDataType() : name -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@d003cd
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode            : Resolved : generatedAlias0.name -> test0_.name
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlWalker                   : processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( {select clause} test0_.id ) ( FromClause{level=1} test test0_ ) ( where ( = ( test0_.name test0_.id name ) ? ) ) )
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.u.JoinProcessor                : Using FROM fragment [test test0_]
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker               : select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (test)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{select clause}'
    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'test0_.id as id1_0_' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=com.example.demo.entity.Test, tableAlias=test0_}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'test0_.name as name2_0_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[generatedAlias0], fromElementByTableAlias=[test0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'test test0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias0,role=null,tableName=test,tableAlias=test0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.example.demo.entity.Test}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'test0_.name' {propertyName=name,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=name,path=generatedAlias0.name,tableAlias=test0_,className=com.example.demo.entity.Test,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
          |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'test0_.id' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=com.example.demo.entity.Test, tableAlias=test0_}
          |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'name' {originalText=name}
          \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@d003cd}

[           main] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.example.demo.entity.Test as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.name=:param0
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : SQL: select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_ from test test0_ where test0_.name=?
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl            : parse() - HQL: delete from com.example.demo.entity.Test x where x = ?1 or x = ?2 ... or x = ?2500
[           main] o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker                   : throwQueryException() : no errors
```

The Sample code is uploaded in github the link to which is : https://github.com/Anand450623/Stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried `testRepository.deleteAllI();` instead of `testRepository.deleteAllInBatch();` ?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: If run your code and everything works fine.

Comment: @AvijitBarua testRepository.deleteAll() is very slow. It deletes the record one by one and cause massive performance impact where the rows to be deleted are large in number.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Actually, the errorLog is quite big and i have to implement logging to get the complete error Log. Meanwhile you can go through the log i'm getting on console. The above two lines are repeated multiple times in my ErrorLog and these are the only lines that i see in my errorLog.

Comment: This does not help. I need the Hibernate error message

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have implemented loggers and updated the stacktrace from two packages of hibernate. Please check the errorlog if these are of some use...

Also, I have updated my code in git with loggers implemenetd. You may look at the code once and play with the loggers.

Comment: I can't see any exception thrown? Why do you think something does not work?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sir, I have tried to log the error trace by every means but I'm unable to locate the exact package which is throwing error also, the stack trace is so huge that it is getting out of console everytime and each time i'm left with one or two lines of error which are repeated multiple times. As of my latest run the error im getting is:

at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:127)

The above line is repeated n number of times and is getting out of console capacity and thus i'm not able to trace the exact error trace.

Comment: Again, it's a request that if you can clone the code from my repo and run it once in your local system it will be a great help for understanding my problem and then may be you can provide some actual solution or reference for my problem.

Comment: Please show use the actual stack trace. The size of the console buffer of an IDE can be configured. Alternatively you can redirect the console output into a file.

Comment: @JensSchauder Sir, i have updated my comments on jira https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1561 and also updated the logs which is most probably the full stack trace with some other log files as well. Please check and comment if you need any other inputs from my side.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a JPQL query to make `deleteAll()` delete in batch rather than one by one.

However, you might actually want to drop the orm-framework entirely. A common experience is that even though it looks like a good idea in the beginning, it almost turns up with issues like the one you gave here :/ you could read https://www.toptal.com/java/how-hibernate-ruined-my-career The gist of it is: it's hard to debug, you can't avoid writing native SQL in most cases anyway, JPQL limits your expressiveness and it's extremely invasive in how you model (e.g. you can't do immutability in a lot of casee).

Spring has an excellent JdbcTemplate, but keep in mind that also have drawbacks, mainly that you have to write the mapping yourself - that said it's not that much code. That said the benefits are huge. So if a JPQL query doesn't work, consider if using JPA (hibernate?) is the right choice to begin with

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to implement my own deleteInBatch method with native sql,

something like

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="delete from table_x where id in (:ids)", nativeQuery=true)
void deleteBatch(List<String> ids);
```

The problem is this piece of code over here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blame/a31c39db7a12113b5adcb6fbaa2a92d97f1b3a02/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/QueryUtils.java#L409

Which generates a awfull sql, not suited for large number of elements